# Oracle Trigger to update a running total of quantity filled

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have two tables below and need to create a trigger that when an execution is created with a corresponding Order_id that the quantity of the execution is added to Quantity_filled in the Order table this needs to be a cumulative amount as one or more executions can be added to an Order and the version in the order table is incremented by 1.

Have managed a couple of date triggers but struggling with this.

ORDER TABLE

```
Key  Field              Type           Description
--------------------------------------------------------
P    ORDER_ID           Number(6)      Order identifier.
     CREATE_DATETIME    Date           Date of order.
F    INSTRUMENT_ID      Number(6)      Instrument identifier.
     AMEND_DATETIME     Date           Date of last order amendment or deletion.
     QUANTITY           Number(12)     QUANTITY
     VERSION            Number(2)      Order version.
     QUANTITY_FILLED    Number(12)     Quantity Filled
```

EXECUTION TABLE

```
Key  Field              Type           Description
--------------------------------------------------------
P    EXECUTION_ID       Number(6)      Unique execution identifier.
     BUY_SELL           Char(1)             Buy/Sell indicator:
                                             ‘B’ – buy;
                                             ‘S’ – sell;
     EXEC_DATETIME      Date                Date of execution.
F    INSTRUMENT_ID      Number(6)      Instrument identifier.
     EXECUTION_PRICE    Number(12)     Price in dealt currency.
     QUANTITY           Number(12)     Execution quantity.
F    ORDER_ID           Number(6)      Order identifier.
```

Have tried this for the Quantity update but get errors.  Am accessing throughout the internet but can't see what they are until I'm back in Uni tomorrow.

Create Trigger ExecQuantityUpdate 
AFTER INSERT ON Execution  BEGIN    Update ORDERS set QUANTITY_FILLED = NEW.QUANTITY WHERE ORDER.QUANTITY_FILLED = NEW.QUANTITY END ;

---

Tried this but still getting errors

```
Create Trigger ExecQuantityUpdate 
AFTER INSERT ON Execution
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN
UPDATE orders
   SET quantity_filled = quantity_filled + NEW.quantity
 WHERE order_id = NEW.order_id 
   AND id = NEW.execution_id;

END
```

Comment: Why use a trigger? You can retrieve the running total quite easily using a SQL query (e.g. put into a view). As a general rule of thumb: don't store data that can be derived from the existing one.

Comment: Each amendment to the order table needs to be tracked.  As each execution is added or removed from the order table the new version will be output to an audit table.

Comment: Is there a chance someone could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Posts are looking more professional even if no one is taking any notice.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be `:NEW` instead of just `NEW`